# how do you install native-base?

Tags: react-native, native-base

[image: Screenshot of output]
Here my errors with my commands.

Command i tried to execute:

`npm install native-base --save`

Here error output:

```
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/GeekyAnts/theme.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jaber\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-21T08_15_50_391Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I was also encountering same problem, so i installed native base using this  - > : npm install native-base@2.12.1 --save --verbose .

Answer (score 0):

First, install `git` on your system. `Native Base` need pull package from `ssh://git@github.com/GeekyAnts/theme.git` by `git` command.
Make sure your git location stay in system's path environment by using this command:

```
git --version
```